# adding bookmark to mobile browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, browser, addition, bookmarks

There exist javascript APIs for adding bookmarks to browser using javascript, but it works only on Desktop

**Firefox**

window.sidebar.addPanel(location.href,document.title,"");

**IE**

window.external.AddFavorite(location.href,document.title);

http://www.hostingfanatic.com/webdev/add-to-bookmarks-javascript/

The above site hosts the code for it, the functionality works in Desktop FireFox and InternetExplorer but not in Desktop chrome or Safari.

The add bookmark also doesnt work on android default browser or android FireFox browser.

It also doesnt work on IOS Safari, on IPad 1 and IPad 2

Is there any javascript API that allows the add bookmark functionality programmatically via javascript in mobile browsers?

If not, is there any other way to achieve this programmatically in mobile browsers?

Also will Phonegap or rooting the android phone, help in any way to achieve this?

I am open to all views.

Comment: *rooting the android phone* conjures strange visions.